# TypeScript: Getting a class/constructor of the object at runtime

Tags: typescript, introspection

For debugging purposes, I want a `toString()` method of an abstract class to print of which subclass the instance actually is.

```
abstract FrameModel {
    ...
    public toString() {
        var classOfThis = ?????;
        return `FrameModel<${classOfThis}>#${this.vertexId}`;
    }
}
```

Also it would be great if I could use that class in TypeScript to access the `static` members; in other words, if I got the JavaScript constructor function to which TypeScript puts the `static` fields.

I've tried

```
var classOfThis = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
```

But that's not it :)

Comment: Works for me in Chrome Version 58 (class: B, class: C); but does not work in IE11 (class: undefined, class: undefined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor` does indeed work:

```
type AConstructor = {
    new(): A;
    name: string;
}

abstract class A {
    toString(): string {
        return `class: ${ (Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor as AConstructor).name }`;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

let b = new B();
console.log(b.toString()); // class: B

let c = new C();
console.log(c.toString()); // class: C
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09new()%3A%20A%3B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20A%20%7B%0A%09toString()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09%09%2F%2Freturn%20%60class%3A%20%24%7B%20(this.constructor%20as%20AConstructor).name%20%7D%60%3B%0A%09%09return%20%60class%3A%20%24%7B%20(Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor%20as%20AConstructor).name%20%7D%60%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20A%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0Aconsole.log(b.toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20class%3A%20B%0A%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20C()%3B%0Aconsole.log(c.toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20class%3A%20C))

I'm not sure why it doesn't for you, I'll need to see more of your code.
In any case, you can also use: `this.constructor`:

```
toString(): string {
    return `class: ${ (this.constructor as AConstructor).name }`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this way, which correctly infers the right types for Intellisense etc.:

```
interface ConstructorOf<T> {
  new(): T;
}
class Animal {
  get cls(): ConstructorOf<this> {
    return this.constructor as any;
  }
  clone() {  
    const ret = new this.cls;
    return ret;
  }
}
class Mammal extends Animal {
  // Nothing yet.
}
const animal1 = new Animal;
const animal2 = animal1.clone();
const mammal1 = new Mammal;
const mammal2 = mammal1.clone();
```

TS PlayGround: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxQK4JjpQDyMAPACoB8yA3gLABQyyIEA7gBQCUAXMkoBuZgF9mCADZwsWZAEEQwALZxJ9ZqwDmEMMilZeAjNlwEipCmAAWwLLUYtWyKLrxQQyG3YB0CTDj4hMTIMqEgAJ4iTuJOUpgQvPSsms7+pi66yAC8bJxetlh+kljRzplg7p6uYGXIsbFSMnIAsnDKquoQAB6QIAAmcooqahpOAPTjyABy6N4gWsgRuj5iEgF6cEqdAIw5eRwK22rR6TjhI5IATPtblzvFCbynG8iqHWp7ueyHbR+SLwy706N1ywM+j3Yz2YQA